# Why is there this white spot on this banana tree?

Tags: trees, plant-health, fruit-trees, banana

What is causing this white spot on this banana tree?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be powder mold, If it's mold, mildew, fungus, you need a good fungicide, I'd recommend a metal based one.
In a pinch, cinnamon will knock it back..